# Developing custom CMS with CakePHP, with multilangauge support

Tags: cakephp, content-management-system

for some purposes, i have to develop custom cms application, and will use CakePHP as framework, since i have working knowledge using it, and cms will be simple one (it will be news portal).

i need your opinion how to develop multilanguage support, is it better to store data about articles in one table, with separate column for each language, or to keep translations in separate table?

can you share your experience.

tnx in adv!

Answer (score 5):

A good database design recommends to add a new table to hold translations. The next you'll add a new language all you have to do is to add a new line (instead of adding a new column in the original table).